# Sharepoint Calendar List: Troubleshooting Anonymous Access

Tags: sharepoint, calendar, sharepoint-2007, anonymous

Having problem getting anonymous access to work for a calendar list in a MOSS 2007 internet web.

Have an authenticated publishing web that is extended with a anonymous only web:  web1 is publishing site,  authenticated and is extended into web2 which is anonymous.
In Central admin

- Web1 is default zone.  Allows anonymous and has intergrated authenticaiton enabled
- Web2 is internet zone.  Allows anonymous,  no integrated authentication.

In site collection

- Web1 - Enable Team Collaboration Lists, which provides the calendar
        Set permissions to allow anonymous to access entire web site

Navigate to web1/lists/calendar/calendar.aspx  and you are authenticated if not already

Navigate to web2/lists/calendar/calendar.aspx  401 access denied

Go to calendar permissions, set anonymous allowed permissions to View items.

Navigate again and same results as above for web1 and web2.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Steps to enable

1. Remove all anonymous access from the site.
2. Deactivate the ViewFormPagesLockdown Feature
3. Make sure that the calendar inherits its permission from the site that it is in and calendar items inherit from the calendar.
4. Do an IISreset and close all browsers.
5. Wait a minute or two (Not completely necessary after the IISreset, but still a good idea if you are testing on the server console)
6. Turn anonymous access on at the site level
7. Close the browser.
8. Browse to the website as anonymous user.
9. Click on a navigation link to browse to the calendar.aspx
10. Click on an event in the calendar to display the details on the Dispform.aspx

Credit goes to Paul Stork at MindSharp for finding this answer for us.